# Defragment a FILESTREAM data container

Tags: sql, defrag, filestream

Has anyone ever tried to defrag a FILESTREAM data container using the Windows Disk Defragmenter?  Does this work without taking the FILESTREAM enabled database offline?

If this doesn't work, can someone recommend an alternate solution (hopefully inexpensive)?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Defraggler](http://www.piriform.com/) or [contig](http://www.sysinternals.com/) - both seem to defrag files that are in use, provided their size doesn't change.

I'm *not* sure whether they will work for FILESTREAM data containers though, but it's certainly worth a shot.

Make a full backup beforehand, of course.

Answer (score 0):

Defragmenting regularly is listed as one of [FILESTREAM best practices](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd206979.aspx), so I think you should be fine.